# Removing string from string array at particular index

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, list, data-structures

I am trying to write an algorithm to delete a name from list of names at particular index. Initially i will read a file line by line. The file would be like this :

```
amelie barbon cat dog thomas | 3
raty  pertw ituy |5
```

Now for example we see the first line where we have three(3) at last, so here we have to to read the number at last for each line , this number is `blackNumber`, so called because after reading this number we have to delete the each string at this index one by one until we have 1 string left in the string array. And that only left string is our answer.

For example:
`Cat` will be deleted in first iteration, and the list will become

`amelie barbon dog thomas`

Now `dog` will be deleted and then `thomas`,after these two similar deletion the list will be:

```
 amelie barbon
```

Up to here my code is working fine, But now we have to delete at index 3 and the
but there are 2 elements only in the list, so the next deletion counter has to start like this :

```
amelie(index:1)-> barbon(index:2)->amelie(index:3)
```

And the string `amelie` must be deleted, which will remain `barbon` in the list, and that's the answer is. (This last step when total number of list elements are less then blackNumber, then i am not able to get the logic that how to do).

What i have tried is below:(which will run infinitely when list count is smaller than `blackNumber`)

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("C:\\Users\\Mohit\\Desktop\\PolmStudio Tasks\\anmeDelete\\anmeDelete\\file.txt"))

                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    List<string> list = null;
                    string line = reader.ReadLine(); ;
                    if (null != line)
                    {
                        list = new List<string>();

                        string[] digits = line.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\n', '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                        for (int i = 0; i < digits.Count() - 1; i++)
                        {
                            list.Add(digits[i]);
                        }
                        int blacknumber = Convert.ToInt32(digits[digits.Count() - 1]) - 1;
                        do
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++)
                            {
                                if (i == blacknumber)
                                {
                                    list.RemoveAt(i);
                                }
                            }
                        } while (list.Count > 1);

                    }
                    foreach (string str in list)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(str);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("");
                }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should clarify that the index implies the array and not the string (file line). Does the result only need one name to survive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the given suggestion and solution your suggestion gave me idea that i cannot change the list items position which are to be deleted, but i can change the blackNumber using `%` operator, so many friends gave me idea about how to do thanks to them but every one's algo is missing some condition. Below is the working solution which implements all necessary conditions :

```
 string line = reader.ReadLine();
                    if (null != line)
                    {
                        list = new List<string>();

                        string[] digits = line.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\n', '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                        for (int i = 0; i < digits.Count() - 1; i++)
                        {
                            list.Add(digits[i]);
                        }
                        int blacknumber = Convert.ToInt32(digits[digits.Count() - 1]);
                        int saveBlackNum = blacknumber;
                        do
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++)
                            {
                                if ((list.Count < (blacknumber)))
                                {
                                    if(blacknumber % list.Count==0 )
                                    {
                                        blacknumber = list.Count();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        blacknumber = ((blacknumber) % list.Count());
                                    }                                  
                                    break;
                                }
                                if ((list.Count >= (blacknumber)))
                                {
                                    if (i == blacknumber - 1)
                                    {
                                        list.RemoveAt(blacknumber - 1);
                                        blacknumber = saveBlackNum;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } while (list.Count > 1);

                    }
                    foreach (string str in list)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(str);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("");
```

May be helpful to some one else in future.

Answer (score 2):

I think, what you're looking for is using modulo `%` of element `n` by `length`

Since you're doing it with a List, you could do something:
`int listIndex = i % list.Count;`

I believe it shall do as you need. The modulo will return the remaining part of the division, hence the index you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Its a simple math. assume your list length is `3`. and you want to remove `5th` element.

`5 % (3 - 1) = 1`. so you must remove item at index `1` i.e `2nd` element.

If the index of element that you are trying to remove is less than count of list then you just normally remove it.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>{"amelie", "barbon", "cat", "dog", "thomas"};

int blacknumber = 3;
blacknumber--; // because indexes are 0 based

do
{
    list.RemoveAt(blacknumber < list.Count ? blacknumber : blacknumber % list.Count);
} while (list.Count > 1);


Console.WriteLine(list[0]); // prints barbon
```

<s>Side note:</s>

Do not use `Count()` because it calls Enumerable.Count from linq. its not optimum. you can directly use the property of list. with `list.Count` (without parenthesis.)

Comment: `Enumerable.Count()` is optimal for anything which implements `ICollection<T>` or `ICollection` - which includes arrays and lists. It's only slow for objects that only implement `IEnumerable<T>` or `IEnumerable`. So in other words, `Enumerable.Count()` is always the equal best choice.

Comment: @M.Kazem thanks for teh answer, you gave me idea to do..but your algo wioll break in condition , for example when blackNumber=6 and list count =3, we will get  6%3= 0 so the blackNumber will be '0' now, whereas it should be '3' to delete the element at third number, I have give the solution below, which will full-fill all conditions. Again thankyou so much for giving guidance and answer.

Comment: @struggling i forgot something. When you say `blacknumber = 3` you want to remove 3rd item but notice that indexes are 0 based. So you must remove at index 2 to remove 3rd item. See the edited code. Now it should work for any case.

Answer (score 1):

I have a simpler solution. The only case I don't know based on your question is what happens if the blackNumber is 1. Will the answer be amelia or thomas?

Heres my code

```
            var arr = new List<string>() { "amelie", "barbon", "cat", "dog", "thomas" };
            var goal = blackline - 2;
            if (goal > -1)
            {
                if (arr.Count > goal)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(arr[goal]);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(arr[arr.Count - 1]);
                }
            }
            else
            {                    
                Console.WriteLine(arr[0]); //if blackline is 1 and answer is suppose to be amelia
                //Console.WriteLine(arr[arr.Count - 1]); //If blackline is 1 and answer is suppose to be thomas
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the inner loop to the following and you will get your required answer:

```
do
{
    int i =0;

    if (blacknumber >= list.Count()) i = blacknumber % list.Count();
    else i = blacknumber;

    list.RemoveAt(i);
} while (list.Count > 1);
```

Comment: I agree with M.kazem Akhgary. I will update the code snippet.

Answer (score -1):

I'm having trouble understanding what you want, is this what you want? To stop removing items if there are less items in that line than the blacknumber? 'if (i == blacknumber && list.Count >= blacknumber)'

Comment: please understand the code first, My code already delete the list item at 3rd index , but after deletion when items are less than blackNumber then it is not able to find the 3rd index and it run infinitely.

Comment: It sounds like I am understanding you correctly and the above should work, because each time before you move an item it will make sure that there is enough items to remove.

Comment: Oh I see. Remove While list.Count >1 cause this is whats making it run forever.

Comment: You have your for loop inside the do while loop. You only need one or the other, and either way you have to add 'list.Count >= blacknumber' in either the while loop, or the if statement in the for loop.